# Are "che", "che cosa" and "cosa" interchangeable in simple "what questions"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

When I want to ask "what do you have for breakfast?", can I use any of the three, "che", "che cosa", or "cosa", to ask the question?

I'm not referring to specific structures like "che ore sono?".

Comment: I live in Tuscany, and agree with egreg, but here "che" is the most colloquial and "cosa" is less used. @Walter Tross (comment on egreg answer) I think "che vuoi?" assume different meaning depending on tone used to say it, but still a bit rude if you do not use for example with a friend.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the example sentence you can use any of them; but

- *che*, in my region, sounds strange alone in a question, but it is widely used in other parts of Italy (see later);
- *che cosa* is “grammatically correct“ anywhere;
- *cosa* is the most colloquial.

Some purists frown upon *cosa*, but since they should blame Alessandro Manzoni for the usage, they can't say it too loudly. See http://www.mauriziopistone.it/testi/discussioni/gramm04_cosa.html for *cosa* as interrogative pronoun in Manzoni and other examples.

Addressing somebody with *Che vuoi per colazione?* may cause raised eyebrows in some parts of Italy and sound formal. Not too formal, though. Conversely, *Cosa vuoi per colazione* may sound funny in the *Che* regions.

Comment: I basically agree, but what makes you consider *che* the “most formal” one?

Comment: @DaG Maybe I feel it so because of regional usage. Hearing someone here saying *Che vuoi?* is very uncommon.

Comment: Yes, perhaps it depends on different parts of Italy (I believe *cosa* prevails in the North, while *che* in Centre-South), and even on different sentences. *Che c'è?* or *Che t'hanno detto a scuola?* sound quite natural to me, not to mention (quite regional) expressions like *Ma che ci avrai da ridere!?*

Comment: @DaG Thanks for the remarks, I changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: Funny, _che vuoi?_ sounds a bit harsh to my Roman ears, like "what the heck/... to you want", but, e.g., _che prendi?_ (at the bar) does not.