# "Per che", "per cosa", "per che cosa" - can I use all the three alternatives in the meaning of "what for"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I am aware of the question [Are "che", "che cosa" and "cosa" interchangeable in simple "what questions"?](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/1964/6590), however it does not answer directly this special use case.

I was recently learning the phrase "*What are our efforts for?*" in [Duolingo](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/25485648), and I answered "***Per che** sono i nostri sforzi?*" Duolingo was not happy and corrected me to "***Per cosa** sono i nostri sforzi?*"

My question is: in the use together with *per*, in the meaning of *what for*, can I use all the three Italian "what-alternatives", or is only *per cosa* correct?

1. ***Per che** sono i nostri sforzi?*
2. ***Per cosa** sono i nostri sforzi?*
3. ***Per che cosa** sono i nostri sforzi?*

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: @Hachi I don't think the first is ungrammatical. It's *uncommon* in current Italian.

Comment: @Hachi: I've found this example: ["Per chi e per che si vota domani?"](https://www.repubblica.it/speciali/politica/elezioni-europee2014/2014/05/24/news/quanto_conta_il_voto_last_minute-87026400/). But I would also like to have an answer to this question because I'm under the impression of having found "per che" very rarely. Maybe the problem is that, in oral speech, "per che ...?" can be confused with "perché ...?", which have different meaning?

Comment: But, @Hachi, "per che si vota domani?" has a different meaning of "perché si vota domani?".

Comment: This is precisely what I have said in my previous comment, @Hachi.  And I cannot see any grammatical reason why "per che si vota domani?" should be not allowed, but it could be that such construction isn't really used. For this reason, I would find ***an answer*** to this question also helpful to me.

Comment: @Hachi it's not ungrammatical it's simply confusing (with perché)  and probably avoided for this reason. I wouldn't for sure use it, but I'm from northern Italy and the use of "che" for "che cosa" is in general more central/southern, so can't say how common it is.

Comment: @Hachi A *pronoun* (a "deputy" noun) is perfectly functional as an object. If I understand correctly, *che* is a pronoun in Italian. Hence I cannot see your reasoning that "the first one is ungrammatical, the object is missing". I am not objecting that the sentence is ungrammatical because that is what I simply don't know, but I cannot agree with your *reasoning* based on the missing object.

Comment: *Che* is relative pronoun in *Voglio il libro **che** parla di Michelangelo*. It's not always a relative pronoun, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three sentences are grammatically equivalent.

However, the interrogative pronoun *che* is very frequently reinforced with *cosa*; however, *che cosa* is often simplified into *cosa* in spoken language.

Why the pleonastic *cosa* is attached to *che*? Quite likely because it underlines the interrogative role of *che*, which has several other functions in Italian.

In the spoken Tuscan language that Manzoni studied for his definitive edition of “I promessi sposi”, dropping the *che* was frequent and Manzoni removed the *che* in most instances. One can find just *che* as interrogative pronoun in the novel, but only in narrations or when said by high level people: Manzoni wanted common people in his novel to speak like common people in Tuscany at his time.

Why is Duolingo correcting your grammatically correct sentence? Because the form with just *che* doesn't belong to current commonly spoken Italian, where *che cosa* or *cosa* would be used. In this case, *per che* may be confused with the interrogative *perché*. Not the specific case, where *perché* would be meaningless; but *per che si vota oggi?* (found in the comments) is very different from *perché si vota oggi?*.

This doesn't imply that you cannot use *che* in that or other contexts. Depending on the Italian region you're in, you can hear any of *che vuoi?*, *che cosa vuoi?* or *cosa vuoi?*, even by the same speaker in different contexts.

See http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/cosa-o-che-cosa-che_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/ for more information on *che/che cosa/cosa*.